# Custom output file format write with Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a requirement to write the following output format.

```
primary_key_value^attribute1:value1;attribute2:value2;attribute3:value3;attribute4:value4
```

The output will be written to a file. I can concat the values manually and make a string out of it. Are there any best practices that I can follow to get Spark to write this output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the name of the column with `concat` or `concat_ws` and write semi colons as separators. In scala, it would look like this:

```scala
val df = Seq((0, "val1", "val2", "val3")).toDF("id", "col1", "col2", "col3")
val res = df
  .select(df.columns.map(c => concat_ws(":", lit(c), col(c)).alias(c)) : _*)
res.show()
```

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  id|     col1|     col2|     col3|
+----+---------+---------+---------+
|id:0|col1:val1|col2:val2|col3:val3|
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

And then:

```scala
res.write.option("sep", ";").csv("...")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was trying with .map(xs => xs.mkString(",").split(",").zip(list).map{ case (x,y) => (y,x)}).show(false), but it was converting the dataframe to struct. This is brilliant

Answer (score 1):

In Pyspark, for each column you can use the `concat` function, to concatenate the column name and its value, and apply all of this in the `select` operator.

After you write this with the csv function :

```py
df.select(* [f.concat(col, f.lit(":"), f.lit(col)) for col in df.columns] ).write.option("header", "false").option("delimiter", ";").csv("../path")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help